# How To add a horizintal listview inside a column in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-layout

i am building a layout where i need to add a horizintal listview inside a column ,  i,ve tried making it expanded or flexible , and nothind seems to work , this is the column that i am putting the list in :

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  HomePage({super.key});

  double? h;

  double? w;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: (h! * 0.02)),
              child: Container(
                width: w! * 0.09,
                height: h! * 0.06,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                ),
                child: Image.asset(
                  "assets/images/menu_from_left.png",
                  // fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                ),
              )),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: h! * 0.04, left: 15.0),
            child: Text(
              " Discover New Opportunities !",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: h! * 0.02,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
              child: Row(children: [
                Icon(Icons.search),
                Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: "Search for new Jobs"),
                  showCursor: true,
                  cursorColor: Colors.black,
                ))
              ]),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: h! * 0.0119,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
            child: Text(
              "For You !",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: h! * 0.0119,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 140,
            width: 200,
            child: Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                // shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                  return ItemBuilder(h, w, cards[index]);
                }),
                itemCount: cards.length,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the listview item that i am trying to create , it should have more than one item m but i was just trting it first and it didn't work for one item  :

```
Widget ItemBuilder(h, w, Map mp) {
  return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        child: Container(
          height: 200,
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                            child: Image.asset(
                              mp["image"],
                              width: w! * 0.28,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              height: w! * 0.18,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Spacer(),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Container(
                              width: w! * 0.25,
                              height: w! * 0.18,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: mp["jobcontainercolor"],
                                  border: Border.all(
                                      color: mp["jobcontainercolor"]),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                              child: mp["jobcontainertitle"]),
                        )
                      ]),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: w! * 0.05,
                ),
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8), child: mp["Job_title"]),
                Spacer(),
                Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 4, 0, 24),
                    child: mp["job_salary"])
              ]),
          color: mp["cardcolor"],
        ),
      ));
}
```

i,ve got couple of exceptions but the last one was this :

```
FlutterError (RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded.
When a row is in a parent that does not provide a finite width constraint, for example if it is in a horizontal scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the horizontal axis. Setting a flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining space in the horizontal direction.
These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.
Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum constraints provided by the parent.
If this message did not help you determine the problem, consider using debugDumpRenderTree():
  https://flutter.dev/debugging/#rendering-layer
  http://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/debugDumpRenderTree.html
The affected RenderFlex is:
  RenderFlex#985b1 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE(creator: Row ← Expanded ← Column ← ColoredBox ← ConstrainedBox ← Container ← ClipRRect ← Padding ← RepaintBoundary ← IndexedSemantics ← _SelectionKeepAlive ← NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification> ← ⋯, parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=1; fit=FlexFit.tight (can use size), constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, h=0.0), size: MISSING, direction: horizontal, mainAxisAlignment: start, mainAxisSize: max, crossAxisAlignment: start, textDirection: ltr, verticalDirection: down)
The creator information is set to:
  Row ← Expanded ← Column ← ColoredBox ← ConstrainedBox ← Container ← ClipRRect ← Padding ← RepaintBoundary ← IndexedSemantics ← _SelectionKeepAlive ← NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification> ← ⋯
See also: https://flutter.dev/layout/
If none of the above helps enough to fix this problem, please don't hesitate to file a bug:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just  remove `Expanded` and use height on Sizedbox,

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: 140,
  // width: 200, //not needed
  child: ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
```

To fixed ItemBuilder issue, remove `Expanded` from Row widget

```dart
  Widget ItemBuilder(h, w, Map mp) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        child: Container(
          height: 200,
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                        child: Image.asset(
                          mp["image"],
                          width: w! * 0.28,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          height: w! * 0.18,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Container(
                        width: w! * 0.25,
                        height: w! * 0.18,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            // color: mp["jobcontainercolor"],
                            border: Border.all(
                                // color: mp["jobcontainercolor"],
                                ),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                        // child: mp["jobcontainertitle"],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),

                // SizedBox(
                //   height: w! * 0.05,
                // ),
                // Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8), child: mp["Job_title"]),
                // Spacer(),
                // Padding(
                //   padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 4, 0, 24),
                //   child: mp["job_salary"],
                // )
              ]),
          // color: mp["cardcolor"],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Also try using SizedBox instead of `Spacer`

Comment: tried this , the same exception is back

Comment: The new issue is coming from  `ItemBuilder`

Comment: Glad to help, You can find more about [layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Expanded` widget directly inside `Column`, try this:

```
 Expanded(child: Container(
        height: 140,
        width: 200,
        child: ListView.builder(
                // shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                  return ItemBuilder(h, w, cards[index]);
                }),
                itemCount: cards.length,
              ),),),
```

`Note` that when you use `Expanded` you don't need to set `height` for horizontal list.

**Update**: in your `ItemBuilder`, you are calling spacer which mean call infinit space in horizontal list view, try add width to this container in `ItemBuilder`:

```
Container(
          height: 200,
          width:300,//<--- add this
          child: Column(
        ...
       ),
),
```

Comment: i've tried this and now i'm getting this error : FlutterError (RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded.
When a row is in a parent that does not provide a finite width constraint, for example if it is in a horizontal scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the horizontal axis.

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out, @hamz